# Amharic calendar issue with ASP.NET and SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I used amharic language calendar which has 13 months. Now if I use, datetime datatype within SQL server to store this date, I cannot store value of 13th month.

Did anyone come across similar situation? Please Help !!!

Comment: Though your question is pretty much clear .. but i request to make your question more brief by giving example what you have and whet you want

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It is very rare where people have used Amharic language with ASP.NET application. If anyone has worked like that, they should have came across same problem.

Comment: You can put your data in varchar column ..

Comment: Dont use datetime to store those date. use nvarchar instead.

Comment: True, but in that case, I cannot perform any datetime related operation to that column, which is not suitable. I have to use that column in report, where it has search feature by date range.

Comment: If you only want to search by date range. It is easy. Your date can be int, when you want to search, just do some progess to cast to int.

Comment: Search by date range means, by day/month/year. I already tried by make that column nvarchar but didn't fit into my requirement. There is also problem with sorting. If I make sorting on that column, it treated as a nvarchar and made incorrect sorting on dates. I am looking for a solution where may be I can convert amharic date to english calendar date, store in database. while displaying that date again convert it to english date to amharic date. But didn't find exact way how to do that.

Comment: You have to convert your amharic date to a juliandate (in gregorian calendar), store the gregorian date in database. Then, when reading back, you have to convert back to your amharic calendar. That means also, if you make a query, you have to convert the date range from amharic to gregorian, query, and when using the results convert back.

Comment: Don't take me otherwise .. but i think your task with 13 month is `challenging rather than hard` .. it is possible that you can not use few `in-build sql server/.net functionalities` but  by creating a new class named `DateTimeWith13Month` .. and keeping datetimevalue as interger is sql server is not that hard..

Comment: To Moumit, I just explained what happened to me. So please don't take it personally.

Comment: To nabuchodonossor, You are correct, we need to do same thing, but didn't get way, how to do that. I am still in searching of converting amharic date to gregorian. [See Here](http://ethiopianlanguages.com/ethiopian-calendar/)

Comment: @PiyushKhatri .. no man .. may be my words are ruff to you .. anyway i working on your need ... trying to give a .net class which supports .. highly required `DateTime` funcations .. just told me do you need that class?? also specify .. .net target version??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find project in c# to convert from Ethiopic date to Gregorian and vice versa: https://github.com/yareda/EthiopicCalendar.

Example of use:

```
private EthiopicCalendar.Calendar ec = new Calendar();
var selected = this.dateTimePicker1.Value;           

// Using the ec instance of the Calendar class
textBox.Text = ec.GregorianToEthiopic(selected.Date);

// Directly using method chaining
label.Text = new EthiopicDateTime(selected.Date).ToString();
```

After conversion to Gregorian date you can store it in SQL Server date column and query it as you want. When you want to show the query result you will just need to convert it back to Amharic date.

Comment: The OP asks how to store an Amharic date in SQL Server, not how to calculate it in C#

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but if he converts date to gregorian calendar then he can store it in sql server date column without a problem?

Comment: @Lesmian This is good. Do you have similar thing for SQL server? I mean conversion of dates from amharic to Gregorian in SQL server. I need that also, because I use stored procedure to display result in my view page. So  what I do, when user selects amharic date, it gets converted in Gregorian and saved in database. Now when I display on view page, it display in Gregorian. It should be in amharic. So I am looking same thing in SQL server. Please let me know if you have it.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri Nah you don't need it in sql server. Just execute your stored procedure to get gregorian date and in c# convert it back to amharic date and pass it to your view. In that case you would use method: ec.GregorianToEthiopic(dateFromStoredProcedure);

Comment: @Lesmian Yes. You are right, we can do same thing. But what happen in my database I have approx 50k records. I get them, and I process at c#, it will take so much time to load page. Thats why I prefer if I have something at sql server side. I am accepting your answer. But still look for sql server side something for me. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri ofc it can take long time for huge number of records, but I would not present 50k records to the user. I'd paginate data and let user browse it if he wants. And parsing single page for e.g. 100 records will be quick. If you don't find sql conversion algorith you could implement your own based on c# implementation I've provided.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a little unclear for me because the title is "Amharic calendar issue with ASP.NET and SQL Server" and your question refers specifically to SQL Server.

In general, you should be storing date/time values as UTC on SQL server.  That way, when you are using ASP.NET/C#, you can reference libraries such as NodaTime and use that to manipulate the calendar that you want to reference.

Alternatively, you can create your own custom class that implements a calendar.  I personally think this would be the easiest way to go if you are unfamiliar with how to use NodaTime, but I strongly recommend NodaTime for tackling this solution.  The below is a stub to implementing your own Calendar.

```
    public class MyCustomCalendar : Calendar
   {

    private int _months;
    private readonly int _totalMonths = 13;

    //i.e, Amharic calendar
    public MyCustomCalendar()
    {
        _months = _totalMonths;
    }

    public override int[] Eras
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public override DateTime AddMonths(DateTime time, int months)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override DateTime AddYears(DateTime time, int years)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetDayOfMonth(DateTime time)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override DayOfWeek GetDayOfWeek(DateTime time)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetDayOfYear(DateTime time)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetDaysInMonth(int year, int month, int era)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetDaysInYear(int year, int era)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetEra(DateTime time)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetMonth(DateTime time)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetMonthsInYear(int year, int era)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetYear(DateTime time)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool IsLeapDay(int year, int month, int day, int era)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool IsLeapMonth(int year, int month, int era)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool IsLeapYear(int year, int era)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override DateTime ToDateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond, int era)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can only store your *Amharic* calendar or any other dates(such as *Persian* calendar) in to ***SQL Server*** that it can be convertible to *Christian date*.

***SQL Server*** only understand `DateTime` type which is a *Christian date*.

You should use a method to convert *Amharic date* to *Christian date* and vice versa.

for example:

```
private DateTime Amharic2Christian(string strAmharicDate)
{
    // Note: Here you have to know the algorithm of converting
    // from Amharic date to Christian date.
}


private string Christian2Amharic(DateTime dtChristianDate)
{
    // Note: Here you have to know the algorithm of converting
    // from Christian date to Amharic date.
}
```

So, when you want to store a given date as *Amharic* (e.g content of a TextBox) into the db, you should use `Amharic2Christian` method to convert it into `DateTime` type, and when you want to show a stored date as *Amharic date* use `Christian2Amharic` method.